# Grid position absolute: text on img

Tags: html, css

It's just a simple implementation of my code. I want to add block with bg color and text on two images, but `position: absolute` doesn't work. What can I do?

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg">
    <div class="text">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of saying '_but position: absolute doesn't work_', (because it's working properly), try to tell us what is the exact behavior you are trying to do.

Comment: @MhdAlaaAlhaj "I want to add block with bg color and text on 2 image". So i want to add text on second image. Block with text must be absolute  for that, but it is not positioned relative to the image

Comment: _I want to add block with bg color and text on 2 image_ means you are trying to add the text for **both** images, instead, you are trying to say: **The second** image, however check my answer below.

Comment: See my solution. Do you need such a result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since class `text` has `position: absolute` but its direct parent (which is `div` in this case) is not positioned, so `.text` will be positioned `absolute` to the nearest positioned parent or to the `body` if no positioned parent appears.

So just add `position: relative` to `.text` parent.

```css
.container{
     display:grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
 .text{
     position:absolute;
     bottom:0;
     left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="relative">
        <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg">
        <div class="text">text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For more information check this link at [freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-the-basics-the-css-position-property/#:%7E:text=The%20CSS%20position%20property%20defines,the%20position%20property%20can%20take.)

> One thing to note is that an element with `position: absolute` is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor. That means that the parent element has to have a position value other than `position: static`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want one text per each item in the grid. Please, tray next time to be a bit more clear with your problem and properly explain the result you expect. Better with an image. That way we won't have to guess and we will be able to better get a solution for you.

That said, first of all you need to create the proper structure. The following could be a nice approach.

```
<figure>
  <img src="pic_name.jpg" alt="">
  <figcaption>Fig.1 - This is a picture showing whatever</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Then, to make `position: absolute` "work", assuming you want the text to overlay the image, you need the parent to be positioned something differente from *static*, which is to say, *relative* or *absolute* too.
Below you can find the solution you are looking for I hope.

```css
.container{ 
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
figure {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
figcaption{
  position:absolute; 
  bottom:5px;
  left:5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="may the force be with you">
    <figcaption>Fig.1 - Grogu</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="may the force be with you">
    <figcaption>Fig.2 - Grogu again</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-scrolling solution because I added the height to the full screen:

```
.container { 
  ... 
  height: 100vh;
  ...
}
```

When using an absolute block, set the parent positioning rule:

```
.container { 
  ...
  position: relative;
}
```

Also, I add these rules to the background block in order to center it:

```
.text {
  ...
  top: 0;  
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  margin: auto;
  ...
}
```

Also, stretch rules for tag `img`:

```
.container img { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

`object-fit: cover` - allows you to preserve aspect ratios when scaling.

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container { 
  display:grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.container img { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.text {
  position:absolute; 
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  margin: auto;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <img src = "https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg">
  <img src = "https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg">
  <div class = "text">
    <p>text<p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but  i mean diffetent text for each img, like another 2 answers

Comment: @wefoyi50, you wrote: *add block with bg color and text on 2 image*. And I thought it was against the background of two images. Oh my bad english.